# Converting SQL query (join with subquery) into KnexJS

Tags: sql, knex.js

I am trying to convert SQL query into KnexJS format, but current KnexJS query gives me the following error.

- syntax error at or near "as" stack: error: syntax error at or near "as"

Here are the original query and the one I've been working on for the KnexJS. 
Please correct my KnexJS query.
Basically, I would like to know how to build KnexJS query - inner join subquery
Thank you in advance!

Original SQL query:

```
select DATE_RANGE.START_DATE, DATE_RANGE.END_DATE, count (distinct DATE) as DATE_COUNT
from TASK_HISTORY
join
(select 
STORE_ID, 
to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(DATE,'99999999'),'YYYYMMDD') - 1,'YYYYMMDD'),'99999999') as END_DATE
, count (distinct DATE) as REC_COUNT
, to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(lag (DATE) over (order by DATE asc),'99999999'),'YYYYMMDD') + 1,'YYYYMMDD'),'99999999') as START_DATE
, count (case when FINISH_TIME is not null then 1 end) as COUNT_FINISHED
, count (case when FINISH_TIME is null then 1 end) as COUNT_UNFINISHED
  from TASK_HISTORY
  where STORE_ID = 43
  group by DATE, STORE_ID
  having count (case when FINISH_TIME is not null then 1 end) = 0
  order by DATE)
  as DATE_RANGE
on TASK_HISTORY.DATE >= DATE_RANGE.START_DATE 
    AND TASK_HISTORY.DATE <= DATE_RANGE.END_DATE
    AND TASK_HISTORY.STORE_ID = 43
group by DATE_RANGE.START_DATE, DATE_RANGE.END_DATE, DATE_RANGE.REC_COUNT
order by DATE_COUNT desc, START_DATE desc
```

Update:

Here is the sulution that worked for me:

```
    await db
      .table("task_history")
      .select('date_range.start_date', 'date_range.end_date')
      .select(db.raw(`count(distinct date) as date_count`))
      .join(
        db
        .select('task_history.store_id')
        .table('task_history')
        .select(db.raw(
          `to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(date,'99999999'),'YYYYMMDD') - 1,'YYYYMMDD'),'99999999') as end_date`
        ))
        .select(db.raw(`count(distinct date) as rec_count`))
        .select(db.raw(
          `to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(lag (date) over (order by date asc),'99999999'),'YYYYMMDD') + 1,'YYYYMMDD'),'99999999') as start_date`
        ))
        .select(db.raw(`count(case when FINISH_TIME is not null then 1 end) as COUNT_FINISHED`))
        .select(db.raw(`count(case when FINISH_TIME is null then 1 end) as COUNT_UNFINISHED`))
        .where('task_history.store_id', 43)
        .groupBy('task_history.date', 'task_history.store_id')
        .having(db.raw(`count(case when FINISH_TIME is not null then 1 end) = 0 order by date`))
        .as('date_range'),
        function () {
          this.on('task_history.date', '>=', 'date_range.start_date')
            .andOn('task_history.date', '<=', 'date_range.end_date')
            .andOn('task_history.store_id', 43)
        }
      )
      .groupBy('date_range.start_date', 'date_range.end_date', 'date_range.rec_count')
      .orderBy('date_count', 'desc')
      .orderBy('start_date', 'desc')
```

Comment: Try to first make minimal example of the part of your query, which doesn't get generated correctly. You can use `.toSQL() ` to print out what knex produces. In current form debugging this could easily take 30 minutes because of amount of unrelated parts in the query and cross checking stuff with original and making sure that original query has valid syntax...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @MikaelLepistö. 
Could you please tell me the syntax that I can build "join subquery"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you-

```
const sql = db.table("task_history")
   .select('DATE_RANGE.START_DATE', 'DATE_RANGE.END_DATE')
   .select(db.raw(`count(distinct DATE) as DATE_COUNT`))
   .innerJoin(
      db.select('store_id')
         .table('task_history')
         .select(db.raw(
            `to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(DATE,'99999999'),'YYYYMMDD') - 1,'YYYYMMDD'),'99999999') as END_DATE`
         ))
         .select(db.raw(`count(distinct DATE) as REC_COUNT`))
         .select(db.raw(
            `to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(lag (DATE) over (order by DATE asc),'99999999'),'YYYYMMDD') + 1,'YYYYMMDD'),'99999999') as START_DATE`
         ))
         .select(db.raw(`count(case when FINISH_TIME is not null then 1 end) as COUNT_FINISHED`))
         .select(db.raw(`count(case when FINISH_TIME is null then 1 end) as COUNT_UNFINISHED`))
         .where('store_id', 43)
         .groupBy('date', 'store_id')
         .having(db.raw(`count(case when FINISH_TIME is not null then 1 end) = 0 order by DATE`))
         .as('DATE_RANGE')
      , function () {
         this.on('DATE_RANGE.START_DATE', '>=', 'TASK_HISTORY.DATE')
            .andOn('TASK_HISTORY.DATE', '<=', 'DATE_RANGE.END_DATE')
            .andOn('TASK_HISTORY.STORE_ID', 43)
      })
   .where('task_history.date', '>=', 'DATE_RANGE.START_DATE')
   .where('task_history.date', '<=', 'DATE_RANGE.END_DATE')
   .groupBy('DATE_RANGE.START_DATE', 'DATE_RANGE.END_DATE', 'DATE_RANGE.REC_COUNT')
   .orderBy('DATE_COUNT', 'desc')
   .orderBy('START_DATE', 'desc')
   .toSQL();
console.log(sql);
```

Comment: Thank you @Fazal Rasel. your example really helped me to sort out my issue.